# VB .NET ODBC Connection with Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dns, odbc

I am using Windows Server Datacenter. I am working on VB .Net 2010 Express Edition with .Net version 4.0.

I am having issue of making ODBC connection with SQL Server on VB .Net.

Here is my code snippet to connect with database.

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cn As Odbc.OdbcConnection
        cn = New Odbc.OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<machine_name>\SQLEXPRESS;UID=<machine_name>\<windows_username>;" & _
                               "PWD=<windows_password>;DATABASE=testdb;")

        Dim mystring As String = "select * from Customers"
        Dim cmd As Odbc.OdbcCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(mystring)
        cn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connected")
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Running this program I am getting below error:

```
ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<machine_name>\<windows_username>'.
```

Primarily the issue sounds that the username and password provided is wrong. But I am using same username and password to access the system.

I think the issue is the way I have provided username and password to the connection string.

I have tried it by making DNS connection with the same database. I have created System DNS,  and trying to connect with below connection string.

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};DNS=<DNS_name>;UID=<windows_username>;PWD=<windows_password>;
```

In this case I am getting following error.

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have checked in both 32 bit and 64 bit DNS, the DNS name specified is available in both versions.

Where I am wrong to make connection? Is there any problem in specifying connection string? If so then please suggest correct connection string to make ODBC connection of SQL Server in VB.Net 2010 Express Edition .

Comment: Your connection string specifies `UID` and `PWD`.  This tells SQL Server you are trying to connect with SQL Authentication (as opposed to Windows Authentication).  Remove `UID` and `PWD` from the connection string and replace with `Integrated Security = True`

Comment: `Integrated Security` parameter works. It connect to SQL Server database with first Connection String specified in the question. But I am still getting `Data source name not found...` error while connecting through DNS connection. The connection string I have supplied is `DNS=testsource;Integrated Security = True;` Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310985 
see point 4 for DSN 
 Add the following code to the DSN button:
    Dim cn as OdbcConnection
    cn = New OdbcConnection ("dsn=MyDSN;uid=sa;pwd=myPassword;")
    Dim mystring As String = "Select * from customers"
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(mystring)
    cn.Open()
    MsgBox("Connected")
    cn.Close()

```
 Standard security
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;
    Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

**Are you using SQL Server 2012 Express? Don't miss the server name syntax Servername\SQLEXPRESS where you substitute Servername with the name of the computer where the SQL Server 2012 Express installation resides.**

```
-----------------------------------

Trusted Connection
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;
    Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;
------------------------

Connecting to an SQL Server instance
The syntax of specifying the server instance in the value of the server key is the same for all connection strings for SQL Server.
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;
Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;

------------------
Prompt for username and password
This one is a bit tricky. First you need to set the connection object's Prompt property to adPromptAlways. Then use the connection string to connect to the database.
oConn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways

oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;"
------------------

Enable MARS
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;
    Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;MARS_Connection=yes;
-------------------

Encrypt data sent over network
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;
Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;Encrypt=yes;

-------------------

Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.\SQLExpress;
    AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

------------------------------
Attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.\SQLExpress;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
    Trusted_Connection=Yes;
-----------------
Database mirroring
If you connect with ADO.NET or the SQL Native Client to a database that is being mirrored, your application can take advantage of the drivers ability to automatically redirect connections when a database mirroring failover occurs. You must specify the initial principal server and database in the connection string and the failover partner server.
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;
     Failover_Partner=myMirrorServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
    Trusted_Connection=yes;
---------------
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. I want to establish ODBC connection through DNS. Is it possible to make DNS connection through ODBC on Windows Server Datacenter?

Comment: You mean DSN? Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools them make the connection. I will not do that I will manage everything from my CODE... This wil share all your DB  this  Windows Server Datacenter is not shared hosting?

Comment: Yes, sorry DSN. I am not aware whether Windows Server Datacenter is shared hosting or not. Yes, through SQL Server credential I am able to connect, but I want to try it with DSN name as well. Does VB .Net can not connect SQL Server through DSN?

Comment: maybe here example DSN there are 2 links see point 4 for DSN http://webpromo-inc.com/support/odbc-connection-string-sample-vb-net-code/    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310985

Comment: No luck. Link of microsoft support forum is very old one. So it is not useful to me as I am having issue with .Net 4.0. And second link is not working.